# How to retrieve data from object, php

Tags: php

I have an object that outputs this on print_r:

```
Dropbox\Client Object
(
    [accessToken:Dropbox\Client:private] => secret
    [clientIdentifier:Dropbox\Client:private] => examples-web-file-browser
    [userLocale:Dropbox\Client:private] => 
    [apiHost:Dropbox\Client:private] => api.dropbox.com
    [contentHost:Dropbox\Client:private] => api-content.dropbox.com
    [root:Dropbox\Client:private] => 
    [host] => Dropbox\Host Object
        (
            [api:Dropbox\Host:private] => api.dropbox.com
            [content:Dropbox\Host:private] => api-content.dropbox.com
            [web:Dropbox\Host:private] => www.dropbox.com
        )

)
```

How do I get just the value "secret"?

**Update:**
var_dump($dbxClient);

outputs:

```
object(Dropbox\Client)#3 (7) {
  ["accessToken":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  string(64) "HrouVh2oRTcAAAAAAAAAARYOdXzK5tA9lCscE24fdnVnt5wYYPSSaK8nITv4PFtc"
  ["clientIdentifier":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  string(25) "examples-web-file-browser"
  ["userLocale":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  NULL
  ["apiHost":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  string(15) "api.dropbox.com"
  ["contentHost":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  string(23) "api-content.dropbox.com"
  ["root":"Dropbox\Client":private]=>
  NULL
  ["host"]=>
  object(Dropbox\Host)#2 (3) {
    ["api":"Dropbox\Host":private]=>
    string(15) "api.dropbox.com"
    ["content":"Dropbox\Host":private]=>
    string(23) "api-content.dropbox.com"
    ["web":"Dropbox\Host":private]=>
    string(15) "www.dropbox.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: `$dropbox->accessToken` ?

Comment: Inside the class scope you can use `$this->accessToken` outside of the class there should be a getter method (e.g. `getAccessToken()`) to receive the `private` property of the class instance.

Comment: Could you post a ´var_dump´ or ´var_export´ instead? Looks like $this->accessToken would work but not $oDropbox->accessToken as the secret is private

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the class file `lib/Dropbox/Client.php` on line `18` of the [official PHP SDK for Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php) there is a method `getAccessToken()` which will return the value of the property `accessToken`.

So in your case this should do the job:

```
var_dump($dbxClient->getAccessToken());
```

In future please have a look at the files of SDKs and APIs first before you posting such questions.

Comment: I guess this is the right and only way to access it, since the variable is private.